# How to achieve a more realistic looking particle floating animation?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm new to canvas, and am trying to create a floating particle animation that looks realistic.

Currently, I am creating 400 particles that are spread randomly over the 400x400 canvas.

Then, in each `requestAnimationFrame`, I am adjusting the `x` and `y` coordinates like so:

```
this.particles[i].x += Math.random() * 0.3 - 0.15;
this.particles[i].y += Math.random() * 0.3 - 0.15;
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how I can make the particles seems like they are more realistically floating.

One way for them to seem more realistic is if they would travel more distance.  Right now, they seem like they are just vibrating, instead of floating. What is one way to achieve a drifting animation such that the particles travel a noticeable distance but don't completely disappear from the canvas?

```js
class ParticleCanvas {
  constructor(canvas, width, height) {
    this.main = {
      element: canvas
    };

    this.buffer = {
      element: document.createElement("canvas")
    };

    this.main.context = this.main.element.getContext("2d");
    this.buffer.context = this.buffer.element.getContext("2d");

    this.main.element.width = this.buffer.element.width = this.width = width;
    this.main.element.height = this.buffer.element.height = this.height = height;

    this.makeParticles(400);
    this.animate();
  }

  makeParticles(n) {
    this.particles = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      this.particles.push(
        new Particle(
          this.width / 2 + Math.random() * this.width - this.width / 2,
          this.height / 2 + Math.random() * this.height - this.height / 2,
          Math.random() * 3 + 2,
          "#919191",
          "circle"
        )
      );
    }
  }

  animate() {
    this.main.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
      this.particles[i].x += Math.random() * 0.3 - 0.15;
      this.particles[i].y += Math.random() * 0.3 - 0.15;
      this.particles[i].draw(this.main.context);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }
}

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, radius, dotColor, particleShape) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.dotColor = dotColor;
    this.particleShape = particleShape;
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x, this.y);
    context.fillStyle = this.dotColor;
    switch (this.particleShape) {
      case "circle":
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();
        break;
      case "square":
        context.fillRect(0, 0, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
        break;
    }
    context.restore();
  }
}


new ParticleCanvas(document.querySelector("canvas"), 400, 400);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Vortexes and a medium to float in.

Sin waves create simple motions that can be used to animate particles.

One of the ways you make particle appear as if floating is to think of them as floating in a medium. The movements of the medium are what makes individual particles move. This has a tendency of making particles near each other move in similar ways.

### Simulating air.

In air the movements tend to be somewhat circular, as a vortex.

To achieve this we can create a set of invisible vortex particles that represent the centers of air vortexes. We move the vortexes around the canvas. Each vortex has a position, a size, and related strength. They move over an area twice as large as the canvas.

Each particle is then moved by each vortex. The amount a particle moves depends on the particle's mass (related to its size) and the distance it is from the vortex center.

Each particle also has momentum (tendency to keep moving), and a abstract buoyancy value that moves the particle up and down over time (to stop them gathering in one place). To give a little spread to the movement a depth (away from eye) adds a little (very tiny little) parallax to the movement.

The animation has 4 steps.

- Update the vortexes moving in large roughly circular paths. If they move off the sides move them to the opposite side (AKA Asteroids space)
- For each vortex update each particle moving the particle along the tangent to the vortex.
- For each particle do drag and buoyancy, and check bounds.
- Draw the particles

### Magic numbers

These types of simulations are very much knife edge in terms of the many magic numbers. At the top of the example I have added some constants to control the simulation.

You can play with the values, there are a wide range of effects that can be achieved, simulating particle in air, water, goo and more.

### Example

Looks best full page.

```js
// request first frame (this starts the whole shebang)
requestAnimationFrame(update);


const doFor =(c,C)=>{var i=0;while(i<c && C(i++)!==true);return i};
const randI = (min, max = min + (min = 0)) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
const rand  = (min = 1, max = min + (min = 0)) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//==================================================================
// WARNING next two control CPU load. 
// Number of particles is width * height / density
const density = 1000;  // particles per pixel squared WARNING Small numbers bad
const airVortexCount = 8;  // number of vortex Warning big number bad
//==================================================================

const airVortexSpeed = 10;  // speed of vortex movement in pixels
const vortexTurn = 0.02; // bigger values and vortex movement more circular
var airList;
const airForceCof = 1;   // amount of force airVortex applys to circle
const circleDrag = 0.99; // drag is 1-circleDrag Must be less than 1
                         // the smaller the number the less movement in circles
const buoyancySpeed  = 0.01; //  Particle buoyancy  speed
var circleList;
const circleMinSize = 2;  // size is radius in pixels
const circleMaxSize = 4;
const floatPhaseCycleMax = 0.02; // Particle buoyancy phase shift. Bigger numbers 
                                 // create faster updown movement
var airWidth,airHeight;
var cirWidth,cirHeight;

function createParticles(){
    airList = {...list};
    circleList = {...list};
    airList.init();
    circleList.init();
    doFor(airVortexCount, () => airList.add({...particle, ...air}).init());
    var circleCount = (canvas.width * canvas.height) / density;
    doFor(circleCount, () => circleList.add({...particle, ...circle}).init());
    airWidth = canvas.width * 2;
    airHeight = canvas.height * 2;
    cirWidth = canvas.width + circleMaxSize * 2;
    cirHeight = canvas.height + circleMaxSize * 2;    
}

function updateAll(){
    airList.update();
    airList.each(circleList.update.bind(circleList));
    circleList.update();
    ctx.beginPath();
    circleList.draw();
    ctx.fill();
}
            


var w,h,cw,ch;
function update(timer){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){  // resize canvas if needed
        cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
        createParticles();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,200,100,0.5)";
    updateAll();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}



// air is a Vortex (bad naming when I started)
const air = {
    update(){
        this.x += Math.cos(this.phase) * airVortexSpeed;
        this.y += Math.sin(this.phase) * airVortexSpeed;
        this.phase += this.phaseShift;
        
        this.x = ((this.x % airWidth) + airWidth) % airWidth;
        this.y = ((this.y % airHeight) + airHeight) % airHeight;
    },
    init(){
        this.x = randI(canvas.width);
        this.y = randI(canvas.height);
        this.size2 = randI(canvas.height * canvas.width);
        this.size = Math.sqrt(this.size2);
        this.phase = rand(Math.PI * 2);
        this.phaseShift = rand(-vortexTurn,vortexTurn);
        return this;
    },
}
// the things that float in air
const circle = {
    init(){
        this.x = randI(canvas.width);
        this.y = randI(canvas.height);
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.size = rand(circleMinSize,circleMaxSize);
        this.mass = this.size ** 3;
        this.depth = rand(0.5,1);
        this.floatPhase = rand(Math.PI * 2);
        this.floatPhaseCycle = rand(floatPhaseCycleMax );
        return this;
    },    
    update(air){  // if air is undefined then do momentum and bouyancy
        if(air === undefined){
            this.dy += Math.sin(this.floatPhase)*buoyancySpeed;
            this.floatPhase += this.floatPhaseCycle;
            this.x += this.dx * this.depth;
            this.y += this.dy * this.depth;
            this.dx *= circleDrag;
            this.dy *= circleDrag;
            this.x = ((this.x % cirWidth) + cirWidth) % cirWidth;
            this.y = ((this.y % cirHeight) + cirHeight) % cirHeight;
            return;
        }
        var x = this.x - (air.x - airWidth / 4);
        var y = this.y - (air.y - airHeight / 4);
        var dist = x * x + y * y;
        if(dist < air.size2){
            dist = Math.sqrt(dist);
            x /= dist;
            y /= dist;
            var force = (1 - dist / air.size) * airForceCof;
            
            // using f = ma  (force = mass * acceleration)
            var a = (force / this.mass) * Math.sign(air.phaseShift);
            this.dx += -y * a;
            this.dy += x * a;
        }
    },
    draw(){
        var x = this.x - circleMaxSize;
        var y = this.y - circleMaxSize;
        ctx.moveTo(x + this.size,y);
        ctx.arc(x,y,this.size,0,Math.PI * 2);
    }
}
// basic particle
const particle = { x : 0,  y : 0, size : 0}
// basic list handles all particle arrays
const list = {
    items : [],
    init(){ this.items = [] },
    add(item) {
        this.items.push(item);
        return item;
    },
    each(callback) { for(const item of this.items) { callback(item) } },
    update(data) { for(const item of this.items) { item.update(data) } },
    draw() { for(const item of this.items) { item.draw() } },
}
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you like this? I am using [Bezier.js](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/) for this.

I checked out some particle libraries. The path of a single particle remembered me of bézier curves somehow. That's why I came up with this idea. <s>For simplicity I just animated one particle.</s>

As you can see I am using the [Bezier.js](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/) library to generate a bézier curve and get its path as points. This look up table can be used to set the position of each particle.

Here is the updated source! Please use "Expand snippet" to show the code without formatting errors. I had do add the whole library into the snippet which causes some indent.

## Edit 1

I actually couldn't wait to see how it looks with multiple particles. By doing so I found out some parameters that should be randomized for each particle:

- The single points of the bézier curves
- The resolution of the look up table
- The starting index of the look up table

```js
var Bezier=function(t){function n(i){if(r[i])return r[i].exports;var e=r[i]={exports:{},id:i,loaded:!1};return t[i].call(e.exports,e,e.exports,n),e.loaded=!0,e.exports}var r={};return n.m=t,n.c=r,n.p="",n(0)}([function(t,n,r){"use strict";t.exports=r(1)},function(t,n,r){"use strict";var i="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t};!function(){function n(t,n,r,i,e){"undefined"==typeof e&&(e=.5);var o=y.projectionratio(e,t),s=1-o,u={x:o*n.x+s*i.x,y:o*n.y+s*i.y},a=y.abcratio(e,t),f={x:r.x+(r.x-u.x)/a,y:r.y+(r.y-u.y)/a};return{A:f,B:r,C:u}}var e=Math.abs,o=Math.min,s=Math.max,u=Math.cos,a=Math.sin,f=Math.acos,c=Math.sqrt,h=Math.PI,x={x:0,y:0,z:0},y=r(2),p=r(3),l=function(t){var n=t&&t.forEach?t:[].slice.call(arguments),r=!1;if("object"===i(n[0])){r=n.length;var o=[];n.forEach(function(t){["x","y","z"].forEach(function(n){"undefined"!=typeof t[n]&&o.push(t[n])})}),n=o}var s=!1,u=n.length;if(r){if(r>4){if(1!==arguments.length)throw new Error("Only new Bezier(point[]) is accepted for 4th and higher order curves");s=!0}}else if(6!==u&&8!==u&&9!==u&&12!==u&&1!==arguments.length)throw new Error("Only new Bezier(point[]) is accepted for 4th and higher order curves");var a=!s&&(9===u||12===u)||t&&t[0]&&"undefined"!=typeof t[0].z;this._3d=a;for(var f=[],c=0,h=a?3:2;c<u;c+=h){var x={x:n[c],y:n[c+1]};a&&(x.z=n[c+2]),f.push(x)}this.order=f.length-1,this.points=f;var p=["x","y"];a&&p.push("z"),this.dims=p,this.dimlen=p.length,function(t){for(var n=t.order,r=t.points,i=y.align(r,{p1:r[0],p2:r[n]}),o=0;o<i.length;o++)if(e(i[o].y)>1e-4)return void(t._linear=!1);t._linear=!0}(this),this._t1=0,this._t2=1,this.update()};l.fromSVG=function(t){var n=t.match(/[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?/g).map(parseFloat),r=/[cq]/.test(t);return r?(n=n.map(function(t,r){return r<2?t:t+n[r%2]}),new l(n)):new l(n)},l.quadraticFromPoints=function(t,r,i,e){if("undefined"==typeof e&&(e=.5),0===e)return new l(r,r,i);if(1===e)return new l(t,r,r);var o=n(2,t,r,i,e);return new l(t,o.A,i)},l.cubicFromPoints=function(t,r,i,e,o){"undefined"==typeof e&&(e=.5);var s=n(3,t,r,i,e);"undefined"==typeof o&&(o=y.dist(r,s.C));var u=o*(1-e)/e,a=y.dist(t,i),f=(i.x-t.x)/a,c=(i.y-t.y)/a,h=o*f,x=o*c,p=u*f,v=u*c,d={x:r.x-h,y:r.y-x},m={x:r.x+p,y:r.y+v},g=s.A,z={x:g.x+(d.x-g.x)/(1-e),y:g.y+(d.y-g.y)/(1-e)},b={x:g.x+(m.x-g.x)/e,y:g.y+(m.y-g.y)/e},_={x:t.x+(z.x-t.x)/e,y:t.y+(z.y-t.y)/e},w={x:i.x+(b.x-i.x)/(1-e),y:i.y+(b.y-i.y)/(1-e)};return new l(t,_,w,i)};var v=function(){return y};l.getUtils=v,l.prototype={getUtils:v,valueOf:function(){return this.toString()},toString:function(){return y.pointsToString(this.points)},toSVG:function(t){if(this._3d)return!1;for(var n=this.points,r=n[0].x,i=n[0].y,e=["M",r,i,2===this.order?"Q":"C"],o=1,s=n.length;o<s;o++)e.push(n[o].x),e.push(n[o].y);return e.join(" ")},update:function(){this.dpoints=[];for(var t=this.points,n=t.length,r=n-1;n>1;n--,r--){for(var i,e=[],o=0;o<r;o++)i={x:r*(t[o+1].x-t[o].x),y:r*(t[o+1].y-t[o].y)},this._3d&&(i.z=r*(t[o+1].z-t[o].z)),e.push(i);this.dpoints.push(e),t=e}this.computedirection()},computedirection:function(){var t=this.points,n=y.angle(t[0],t[this.order],t[1]);this.clockwise=n>0},length:function(){return y.length(this.derivative.bind(this))},_lut:[],getLUT:function(t){if(t=t||100,this._lut.length===t)return this._lut;this._lut=[];for(var n=0;n<=t;n++)this._lut.push(this.compute(n/t));return this._lut},on:function(t,n){n=n||5;for(var r,i=this.getLUT(),e=[],o=0,s=0;s<i.length;s++)r=i[s],y.dist(r,t)<n&&(e.push(r),o+=s/i.length);return!!e.length&&(o/=e.length)},project:function(t){var n=this.getLUT(),r=n.length-1,i=y.closest(n,t),e=i.mdist,o=i.mpos;if(0===o||o===r){var s=o/r,u=this.compute(s);return u.t=s,u.d=e,u}var a,s,f,c,h=(o-1)/r,x=(o+1)/r,p=.1/r;for(e+=1,s=h,a=s;s<x+p;s+=p)f=this.compute(s),c=y.dist(t,f),c<e&&(e=c,a=s);return f=this.compute(a),f.t=a,f.d=e,f},get:function(t){return this.compute(t)},point:function(t){return this.points[t]},compute:function(t){if(0===t)return this.points[0];if(1===t)return this.points[this.order];var n=this.points,r=1-t;if(1===this.order)return f={x:r*n[0].x+t*n[1].x,y:r*n[0].y+t*n[1].y},this._3d&&(f.z=r*n[0].z+t*n[1].z),f;if(this.order<4){var i,e,o,s=r*r,u=t*t,a=0;2===this.order?(n=[n[0],n[1],n[2],x],i=s,e=r*t*2,o=u):3===this.order&&(i=s*r,e=s*t*3,o=r*u*3,a=t*u);var f={x:i*n[0].x+e*n[1].x+o*n[2].x+a*n[3].x,y:i*n[0].y+e*n[1].y+o*n[2].y+a*n[3].y};return this._3d&&(f.z=i*n[0].z+e*n[1].z+o*n[2].z+a*n[3].z),f}for(var c=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.points));c.length>1;){for(var h=0;h<c.length-1;h++)c[h]={x:c[h].x+(c[h+1].x-c[h].x)*t,y:c[h].y+(c[h+1].y-c[h].y)*t},"undefined"!=typeof c[h].z&&(c[h]=c[h].z+(c[h+1].z-c[h].z)*t);c.splice(c.length-1,1)}return c[0]},raise:function(){for(var t,n,r,i=this.points,e=[i[0]],o=i.length,t=1;t<o;t++)n=i[t],r=i[t-1],e[t]={x:(o-t)/o*n.x+t/o*r.x,y:(o-t)/o*n.y+t/o*r.y};return e[o]=i[o-1],new l(e)},derivative:function(t){var n,r,i=1-t,e=0,o=this.dpoints[0];2===this.order&&(o=[o[0],o[1],x],n=i,r=t),3===this.order&&(n=i*i,r=i*t*2,e=t*t);var s={x:n*o[0].x+r*o[1].x+e*o[2].x,y:n*o[0].y+r*o[1].y+e*o[2].y};return this._3d&&(s.z=n*o[0].z+r*o[1].z+e*o[2].z),s},inflections:function(){return y.inflections(this.points)},normal:function(t){return this._3d?this.__normal3(t):this.__normal2(t)},__normal2:function(t){var n=this.derivative(t),r=c(n.x*n.x+n.y*n.y);return{x:-n.y/r,y:n.x/r}},__normal3:function(t){var n=this.derivative(t),r=this.derivative(t+.01),i=c(n.x*n.x+n.y*n.y+n.z*n.z),e=c(r.x*r.x+r.y*r.y+r.z*r.z);n.x/=i,n.y/=i,n.z/=i,r.x/=e,r.y/=e,r.z/=e;var o={x:r.y*n.z-r.z*n.y,y:r.z*n.x-r.x*n.z,z:r.x*n.y-r.y*n.x},s=c(o.x*o.x+o.y*o.y+o.z*o.z);o.x/=s,o.y/=s,o.z/=s;var u=[o.x*o.x,o.x*o.y-o.z,o.x*o.z+o.y,o.x*o.y+o.z,o.y*o.y,o.y*o.z-o.x,o.x*o.z-o.y,o.y*o.z+o.x,o.z*o.z],a={x:u[0]*n.x+u[1]*n.y+u[2]*n.z,y:u[3]*n.x+u[4]*n.y+u[5]*n.z,z:u[6]*n.x+u[7]*n.y+u[8]*n.z};return a},hull:function(t){var n,r=this.points,i=[],e=[],o=0,s=0,u=0;for(e[o++]=r[0],e[o++]=r[1],e[o++]=r[2],3===this.order&&(e[o++]=r[3]);r.length>1;){for(i=[],s=0,u=r.length-1;s<u;s++)n=y.lerp(t,r[s],r[s+1]),e[o++]=n,i.push(n);r=i}return e},split:function(t,n){if(0===t&&n)return this.split(n).left;if(1===n)return this.split(t).right;var r=this.hull(t),i={left:new l(2===this.order?[r[0],r[3],r[5]]:[r[0],r[4],r[7],r[9]]),right:new l(2===this.order?[r[5],r[4],r[2]]:[r[9],r[8],r[6],r[3]]),span:r};if(i.left._t1=y.map(0,0,1,this._t1,this._t2),i.left._t2=y.map(t,0,1,this._t1,this._t2),i.right._t1=y.map(t,0,1,this._t1,this._t2),i.right._t2=y.map(1,0,1,this._t1,this._t2),!n)return i;n=y.map(n,t,1,0,1);var e=i.right.split(n);return e.left},extrema:function(){var t,n,r=this.dims,i={},e=[];return r.forEach(function(r){n=function(t){return t[r]},t=this.dpoints[0].map(n),i[r]=y.droots(t),3===this.order&&(t=this.dpoints[1].map(n),i[r]=i[r].concat(y.droots(t))),i[r]=i[r].filter(function(t){return t>=0&&t<=1}),e=e.concat(i[r].sort(y.numberSort))}.bind(this)),e=e.sort(y.numberSort).filter(function(t,n){return e.indexOf(t)===n}),i.values=e,i},bbox:function(){var t=this.extrema(),n={};return this.dims.forEach(function(r){n[r]=y.getminmax(this,r,t[r])}.bind(this)),n},overlaps:function(t){var n=this.bbox(),r=t.bbox();return y.bboxoverlap(n,r)},offset:function(t,n){if("undefined"!=typeof n){var r=this.get(t),i=this.normal(t),e={c:r,n:i,x:r.x+i.x*n,y:r.y+i.y*n};return this._3d&&(e.z=r.z+i.z*n),e}if(this._linear){var o=this.normal(0),s=this.points.map(function(n){var r={x:n.x+t*o.x,y:n.y+t*o.y};return n.z&&i.z&&(r.z=n.z+t*o.z),r});return[new l(s)]}var u=this.reduce();return u.map(function(n){return n.scale(t)})},simple:function(){if(3===this.order){var t=y.angle(this.points[0],this.points[3],this.points[1]),n=y.angle(this.points[0],this.points[3],this.points[2]);if(t>0&&n<0||t<0&&n>0)return!1}var r=this.normal(0),i=this.normal(1),o=r.x*i.x+r.y*i.y;this._3d&&(o+=r.z*i.z);var s=e(f(o));return s<h/3},reduce:function(){var t,n,r=0,i=0,o=.01,s=[],u=[],a=this.extrema().values;for(a.indexOf(0)===-1&&(a=[0].concat(a)),a.indexOf(1)===-1&&a.push(1),r=a[0],t=1;t<a.length;t++)i=a[t],n=this.split(r,i),n._t1=r,n._t2=i,s.push(n),r=i;return s.forEach(function(t){for(r=0,i=0;i<=1;)for(i=r+o;i<=1+o;i+=o)if(n=t.split(r,i),!n.simple()){if(i-=o,e(r-i)<o)return[];n=t.split(r,i),n._t1=y.map(r,0,1,t._t1,t._t2),n._t2=y.map(i,0,1,t._t1,t._t2),u.push(n),r=i;break}r<1&&(n=t.split(r,1),n._t1=y.map(r,0,1,t._t1,t._t2),n._t2=t._t2,u.push(n))}),u},scale:function(t){var n=this.order,r=!1;if("function"==typeof t&&(r=t),r&&2===n)return this.raise().scale(r);var i=this.clockwise,e=r?r(0):t,o=r?r(1):t,s=[this.offset(0,10),this.offset(1,10)],u=y.lli4(s[0],s[0].c,s[1],s[1].c);if(!u)throw new Error("cannot scale this curve. Try reducing it first.");var a=this.points,f=[];return[0,1].forEach(function(t){var r=f[t*n]=y.copy(a[t*n]);r.x+=(t?o:e)*s[t].n.x,r.y+=(t?o:e)*s[t].n.y}.bind(this)),r?([0,1].forEach(function(e){if(2!==this.order||!e){var o=a[e+1],s={x:o.x-u.x,y:o.y-u.y},h=r?r((e+1)/n):t;r&&!i&&(h=-h);var x=c(s.x*s.x+s.y*s.y);s.x/=x,s.y/=x,f[e+1]={x:o.x+h*s.x,y:o.y+h*s.y}}}.bind(this)),new l(f)):([0,1].forEach(function(t){if(2!==this.order||!t){var r=f[t*n],i=this.derivative(t),e={x:r.x+i.x,y:r.y+i.y};f[t+1]=y.lli4(r,e,u,a[t+1])}}.bind(this)),new l(f))},outline:function(t,n,r,i){function e(t,n,r,i,e){return function(o){var s=i/r,u=(i+e)/r,a=n-t;return y.map(o,0,1,t+s*a,t+u*a)}}n="undefined"==typeof n?t:n;var o,s=this.reduce(),u=s.length,a=[],f=[],c=0,h=this.length(),x="undefined"!=typeof r&&"undefined"!=typeof i;s.forEach(function(o){_=o.length(),x?(a.push(o.scale(e(t,r,h,c,_))),f.push(o.scale(e(-n,-i,h,c,_)))):(a.push(o.scale(t)),f.push(o.scale(-n))),c+=_}),f=f.map(function(t){return o=t.points,o[3]?t.points=[o[3],o[2],o[1],o[0]]:t.points=[o[2],o[1],o[0]],t}).reverse();var l=a[0].points[0],v=a[u-1].points[a[u-1].points.length-1],d=f[u-1].points[f[u-1].points.length-1],m=f[0].points[0],g=y.makeline(d,l),z=y.makeline(v,m),b=[g].concat(a).concat([z]).concat(f),_=b.length;return new p(b)},outlineshapes:function(t,n,r){n=n||t;for(var i=this.outline(t,n).curves,e=[],o=1,s=i.length;o<s/2;o++){var u=y.makeshape(i[o],i[s-o],r);u.startcap.virtual=o>1,u.endcap.virtual=o<s/2-1,e.push(u)}return e},intersects:function(t,n){return t?t.p1&&t.p2?this.lineIntersects(t):(t instanceof l&&(t=t.reduce()),this.curveintersects(this.reduce(),t,n)):this.selfintersects(n)},lineIntersects:function(t){var n=o(t.p1.x,t.p2.x),r=o(t.p1.y,t.p2.y),i=s(t.p1.x,t.p2.x),e=s(t.p1.y,t.p2.y),u=this;return y.roots(this.points,t).filter(function(t){var o=u.get(t);return y.between(o.x,n,i)&&y.between(o.y,r,e)})},selfintersects:function(t){var n,r,i,e,o=this.reduce(),s=o.length-2,u=[];for(n=0;n<s;n++)i=o.slice(n,n+1),e=o.slice(n+2),r=this.curveintersects(i,e,t),u=u.concat(r);return u},curveintersects:function(t,n,r){var i=[];t.forEach(function(t){n.forEach(function(n){t.overlaps(n)&&i.push({left:t,right:n})})});var e=[];return i.forEach(function(t){var n=y.pairiteration(t.left,t.right,r);n.length>0&&(e=e.concat(n))}),e},arcs:function(t){t=t||.5;var n=[];return this._iterate(t,n)},_error:function(t,n,r,i){var o=(i-r)/4,s=this.get(r+o),u=this.get(i-o),a=y.dist(t,n),f=y.dist(t,s),c=y.dist(t,u);return e(f-a)+e(c-a)},_iterate:function(t,n){var r,i=0,e=1;do{r=0,e=1;var o,s,f,c,h,x=this.get(i),p=!1,l=!1,v=e,d=1,m=0;do{l=p,c=f,v=(i+e)/2,m++,o=this.get(v),s=this.get(e),f=y.getccenter(x,o,s),f.interval={start:i,end:e};var g=this._error(f,x,i,e);if(p=g<=t,h=l&&!p,h||(d=e),p){if(e>=1){if(f.interval.end=d=1,c=f,e>1){var z={x:f.x+f.r*u(f.e),y:f.y+f.r*a(f.e)};f.e+=y.angle({x:f.x,y:f.y},z,this.get(1))}break}e+=(e-i)/2}else e=v}while(!h&&r++<100);if(r>=100)break;c=c?c:f,n.push(c),i=d}while(e<1);return n}},t.exports=l}()},function(t,n,r){"use strict";!function(){var n=Math.abs,i=Math.cos,e=Math.sin,o=Math.acos,s=Math.atan2,u=Math.sqrt,a=Math.pow,f=function(t){return t<0?-a(-t,1/3):a(t,1/3)},c=Math.PI,h=2*c,x=c/2,y=1e-6,p=Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,l=Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,v={Tvalues:[-.06405689286260563,.06405689286260563,-.1911188674736163,.1911188674736163,-.3150426796961634,.3150426796961634,-.4337935076260451,.4337935076260451,-.5454214713888396,.5454214713888396,-.6480936519369755,.6480936519369755,-.7401241915785544,.7401241915785544,-.820001985973903,.820001985973903,-.8864155270044011,.8864155270044011,-.9382745520027328,.9382745520027328,-.9747285559713095,.9747285559713095,-.9951872199970213,.9951872199970213],Cvalues:[.12793819534675216,.12793819534675216,.1258374563468283,.1258374563468283,.12167047292780339,.12167047292780339,.1155056680537256,.1155056680537256,.10744427011596563,.10744427011596563,.09761865210411388,.09761865210411388,.08619016153195327,.08619016153195327,.0733464814110803,.0733464814110803,.05929858491543678,.05929858491543678,.04427743881741981,.04427743881741981,.028531388628933663,.028531388628933663,.0123412297999872,.0123412297999872],arcfn:function(t,n){var r=n(t),i=r.x*r.x+r.y*r.y;return"undefined"!=typeof r.z&&(i+=r.z*r.z),u(i)},between:function(t,n,r){return n<=t&&t<=r||v.approximately(t,n)||v.approximately(t,r)},approximately:function(t,r,i){return n(t-r)<=(i||y)},length:function(t){var n,r,i=.5,e=0,o=v.Tvalues.length;for(n=0;n<o;n++)r=i*v.Tvalues[n]+i,e+=v.Cvalues[n]*v.arcfn(r,t);return i*e},map:function(t,n,r,i,e){var o=r-n,s=e-i,u=t-n,a=u/o;return i+s*a},lerp:function(t,n,r){var i={x:n.x+t*(r.x-n.x),y:n.y+t*(r.y-n.y)};return n.z&&r.z&&(i.z=n.z+t*(r.z-n.z)),i},pointToString:function(t){var n=t.x+"/"+t.y;return"undefined"!=typeof t.z&&(n+="/"+t.z),n},pointsToString:function(t){return"["+t.map(v.pointToString).join(", ")+"]"},copy:function(t){return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t))},angle:function(t,n,r){var i=n.x-t.x,e=n.y-t.y,o=r.x-t.x,u=r.y-t.y,a=i*u-e*o,f=i*o+e*u;return s(a,f)},round:function(t,n){var r=""+t,i=r.indexOf(".");return parseFloat(r.substring(0,i+1+n))},dist:function(t,n){var r=t.x-n.x,i=t.y-n.y;return u(r*r+i*i)},closest:function(t,n){var r,i,e=a(2,63);return t.forEach(function(t,o){i=v.dist(n,t),i<e&&(e=i,r=o)}),{mdist:e,mpos:r}},abcratio:function(t,r){if(2!==r&&3!==r)return!1;if("undefined"==typeof t)t=.5;else if(0===t||1===t)return t;var i=a(t,r)+a(1-t,r),e=i-1;return n(e/i)},projectionratio:function(t,n){if(2!==n&&3!==n)return!1;if("undefined"==typeof t)t=.5;else if(0===t||1===t)return t;var r=a(1-t,n),i=a(t,n)+r;return r/i},lli8:function(t,n,r,i,e,o,s,u){var a=(t*i-n*r)*(e-s)-(t-r)*(e*u-o*s),f=(t*i-n*r)*(o-u)-(n-i)*(e*u-o*s),c=(t-r)*(o-u)-(n-i)*(e-s);return 0!=c&&{x:a/c,y:f/c}},lli4:function(t,n,r,i){var e=t.x,o=t.y,s=n.x,u=n.y,a=r.x,f=r.y,c=i.x,h=i.y;return v.lli8(e,o,s,u,a,f,c,h)},lli:function(t,n){return v.lli4(t,t.c,n,n.c)},makeline:function(t,n){var i=r(1),e=t.x,o=t.y,s=n.x,u=n.y,a=(s-e)/3,f=(u-o)/3;return new i(e,o,e+a,o+f,e+2*a,o+2*f,s,u)},findbbox:function(t){var n=p,r=p,i=l,e=l;return t.forEach(function(t){var o=t.bbox();n>o.x.min&&(n=o.x.min),r>o.y.min&&(r=o.y.min),i<o.x.max&&(i=o.x.max),e<o.y.max&&(e=o.y.max)}),{x:{min:n,mid:(n+i)/2,max:i,size:i-n},y:{min:r,mid:(r+e)/2,max:e,size:e-r}}},shapeintersections:function(t,n,r,i,e){if(!v.bboxoverlap(n,i))return[];var o=[],s=[t.startcap,t.forward,t.back,t.endcap],u=[r.startcap,r.forward,r.back,r.endcap];return s.forEach(function(n){n.virtual||u.forEach(function(i){if(!i.virtual){var s=n.intersects(i,e);s.length>0&&(s.c1=n,s.c2=i,s.s1=t,s.s2=r,o.push(s))}})}),o},makeshape:function(t,n,r){var i=n.points.length,e=t.points.length,o=v.makeline(n.points[i-1],t.points[0]),s=v.makeline(t.points[e-1],n.points[0]),u={startcap:o,forward:t,back:n,endcap:s,bbox:v.findbbox([o,t,n,s])},a=v;return u.intersections=function(t){return a.shapeintersections(u,u.bbox,t,t.bbox,r)},u},getminmax:function(t,n,r){if(!r)return{min:0,max:0};var i,e,o=p,s=l;r.indexOf(0)===-1&&(r=[0].concat(r)),r.indexOf(1)===-1&&r.push(1);for(var u=0,a=r.length;u<a;u++)i=r[u],e=t.get(i),e[n]<o&&(o=e[n]),e[n]>s&&(s=e[n]);return{min:o,mid:(o+s)/2,max:s,size:s-o}},align:function(t,n){var r=n.p1.x,o=n.p1.y,u=-s(n.p2.y-o,n.p2.x-r),a=function(t){return{x:(t.x-r)*i(u)-(t.y-o)*e(u),y:(t.x-r)*e(u)+(t.y-o)*i(u)}};return t.map(a)},roots:function(t,n){n=n||{p1:{x:0,y:0},p2:{x:1,y:0}};var r=t.length-1,e=v.align(t,n),s=function(t){return 0<=t&&t<=1};if(2===r){var a=e[0].y,c=e[1].y,x=e[2].y,y=a-2*c+x;if(0!==y){var p=-u(c*c-a*x),l=-a+c,d=-(p+l)/y,m=-(-p+l)/y;return[d,m].filter(s)}return c!==x&&0===y?[(2*c-x)/2*(c-x)].filter(s):[]}var g,d,z,b,_,w=e[0].y,E=e[1].y,S=e[2].y,M=e[3].y,y=-w+3*E-3*S+M,a=(3*w-6*E+3*S)/y,c=(-3*w+3*E)/y,x=w/y,e=(3*c-a*a)/3,k=e/3,O=(2*a*a*a-9*a*c+27*x)/27,T=O/2,N=T*T+k*k*k;if(N<0){var j=-e/3,I=j*j*j,A=u(I),C=-O/(2*A),F=C<-1?-1:C>1?1:C,q=o(F),U=f(A),B=2*U;return z=B*i(q/3)-a/3,b=B*i((q+h)/3)-a/3,_=B*i((q+2*h)/3)-a/3,[z,b,_].filter(s)}if(0===N)return g=T<0?f(-T):-f(T),z=2*g-a/3,b=-g-a/3,[z,b].filter(s);var G=u(N);return g=f(-T+G),d=f(T+G),[g-d-a/3].filter(s)},droots:function(t){if(3===t.length){var n=t[0],r=t[1],i=t[2],e=n-2*r+i;if(0!==e){var o=-u(r*r-n*i),s=-n+r,a=-(o+s)/e,f=-(-o+s)/e;return[a,f]}return r!==i&&0===e?[(2*r-i)/(2*(r-i))]:[]}if(2===t.length){var n=t[0],r=t[1];return n!==r?[n/(n-r)]:[]}},inflections:function(t){if(t.length<4)return[];var n=v.align(t,{p1:t[0],p2:t.slice(-1)[0]}),r=n[2].x*n[1].y,i=n[3].x*n[1].y,e=n[1].x*n[2].y,o=n[3].x*n[2].y,s=18*(-3*r+2*i+3*e-o),u=18*(3*r-i-3*e),a=18*(e-r);if(v.approximately(s,0)){if(!v.approximately(u,0)){var f=-a/u;if(0<=f&&f<=1)return[f]}return[]}var c=u*u-4*s*a,h=Math.sqrt(c),o=2*s;return v.approximately(o,0)?[]:[(h-u)/o,-(u+h)/o].filter(function(t){return 0<=t&&t<=1})},bboxoverlap:function(t,r){var i,e,o,s,u,a=["x","y"],f=a.length;for(i=0;i<f;i++)if(e=a[i],o=t[e].mid,s=r[e].mid,u=(t[e].size+r[e].size)/2,n(o-s)>=u)return!1;return!0},expandbox:function(t,n){n.x.min<t.x.min&&(t.x.min=n.x.min),n.y.min<t.y.min&&(t.y.min=n.y.min),n.z&&n.z.min<t.z.min&&(t.z.min=n.z.min),n.x.max>t.x.max&&(t.x.max=n.x.max),n.y.max>t.y.max&&(t.y.max=n.y.max),n.z&&n.z.max>t.z.max&&(t.z.max=n.z.max),t.x.mid=(t.x.min+t.x.max)/2,t.y.mid=(t.y.min+t.y.max)/2,t.z&&(t.z.mid=(t.z.min+t.z.max)/2),t.x.size=t.x.max-t.x.min,t.y.size=t.y.max-t.y.min,t.z&&(t.z.size=t.z.max-t.z.min)},pairiteration:function(t,n,r){var i=t.bbox(),e=n.bbox(),o=1e5,s=r||.5;if(i.x.size+i.y.size<s&&e.x.size+e.y.size<s)return[(o*(t._t1+t._t2)/2|0)/o+"/"+(o*(n._t1+n._t2)/2|0)/o];var u=t.split(.5),a=n.split(.5),f=[{left:u.left,right:a.left},{left:u.left,right:a.right},{left:u.right,right:a.right},{left:u.right,right:a.left}];f=f.filter(function(t){return v.bboxoverlap(t.left.bbox(),t.right.bbox())});var c=[];return 0===f.length?c:(f.forEach(function(t){c=c.concat(v.pairiteration(t.left,t.right,s))}),c=c.filter(function(t,n){return c.indexOf(t)===n}))},getccenter:function(t,n,r){var o,u=n.x-t.x,a=n.y-t.y,f=r.x-n.x,c=r.y-n.y,y=u*i(x)-a*e(x),p=u*e(x)+a*i(x),l=f*i(x)-c*e(x),d=f*e(x)+c*i(x),m=(t.x+n.x)/2,g=(t.y+n.y)/2,z=(n.x+r.x)/2,b=(n.y+r.y)/2,_=m+y,w=g+p,E=z+l,S=b+d,M=v.lli8(m,g,_,w,z,b,E,S),k=v.dist(M,t),O=s(t.y-M.y,t.x-M.x),T=s(n.y-M.y,n.x-M.x),N=s(r.y-M.y,r.x-M.x);return O<N?((O>T||T>N)&&(O+=h),O>N&&(o=N,N=O,O=o)):N<T&&T<O?(o=N,N=O,O=o):N+=h,M.s=O,M.e=N,M.r=k,M},numberSort:function(t,n){return t-n}};t.exports=v}()},function(t,n,r){"use strict";!function(){var n=r(2),i=function(t){this.curves=[],this._3d=!1,t&&(this.curves=t,this._3d=this.curves[0]._3d)};i.prototype={valueOf:function(){return this.toString()},toString:function(){return"["+this.curves.map(function(t){return n.pointsToString(t.points)}).join(", ")+"]"},addCurve:function(t){this.curves.push(t),this._3d=this._3d||t._3d},length:function(){return this.curves.map(function(t){return t.length()}).reduce(function(t,n){return t+n})},curve:function(t){return this.curves[t]},bbox:function t(){for(var r=this.curves,t=r[0].bbox(),i=1;i<r.length;i++)n.expandbox(t,r[i].bbox());return t},offset:function t(n){var t=[];return this.curves.forEach(function(r){t=t.concat(r.offset(n))}),new i(t)}},t.exports=i}()}]);

class ParticleCanvas {
  constructor(canvas, width, height) {
    this.main = {
      element: canvas
    };

    this.buffer = {
      element: document.createElement("canvas")
    };

    this.main.context = this.main.element.getContext("2d");
    this.buffer.context = this.buffer.element.getContext("2d");

    this.main.element.width = this.buffer.element.width = this.width = width;
    this.main.element.height = this.buffer.element.height = this.height = height;

    this.makeParticles(400);
    this.animate();
  }

  makeParticles(n) {
    this.particles = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      this.particles.push(
        new Particle(
          this.width / 2 + Math.random() * this.width - this.width / 2,
          this.height / 2 + Math.random() * this.height - this.height / 2,
          Math.random() * 3 + 2,
          "#919191",
          "circle"
        )
      );
    }
  }

  animate() {
    this.main.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
      this.particles[i].x = this.particles[i].pathLut[this.particles[i].lutIndex].x;
      this.particles[i].y = this.particles[i].pathLut[this.particles[i].lutIndex].y;
      this.particles[i].draw(this.main.context);

      if(this.particles[i].inverse) {
        this.particles[i].lutIndex--;
      }
      else {
        this.particles[i].lutIndex++;
      }

      if(this.particles[i].lutIndex == 0) {
        this.particles[i].inverse = false;
      }
      if(this.particles[i].lutIndex >= this.particles[i].pathLut.length - 1) {
        this.particles[i].inverse = true;
      }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }
}

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, radius, dotColor, particleShape) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.dotColor = dotColor;
    this.particleShape = particleShape;
    this.bezierResolution = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1024 - 256)) + 256;
    this.lutIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bezierResolution);
    this.inverse = false;

    var randoms = new Array(8);

    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      randoms[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    }

    this.pathLut = new Bezier(
      randoms[0],
      randoms[1],
      randoms[2],
      randoms[3],
      randoms[4],
      randoms[5],
      randoms[6],
      randoms[7]
    ).getLUT(this.bezierResolution);
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x, this.y);
    context.fillStyle = this.dotColor;
    switch (this.particleShape) {
      case "circle":
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();
        break;
      case "square":
        context.fillRect(0, 0, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
        break;
    }
    context.restore();
  }
}

new ParticleCanvas(document.querySelector("canvas"), 400, 400);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```